# Populate select box from database query based on another select box using only 1 table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

Hi guys I am currently creating a website with the main function of booking cars. Therefore the user would be first able to select a car category from the database query which will output the selected car category names. After selecting the car category name, the second select box would then by dynamically updated with a new set of of car names that are associated with the category.

There may have been many similar questions to this however for the website **NO** jQuery or AJAX can be utilized. And other questions and examples often utilize 2 or more tables however I am using only 1 table for this function.

The example below should show how the Select box should be updated:
[Dynamically updated select box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htoFK.jpg)

The table utilized is this:
[Table Utilized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs1Iw.jpg)

My codes are as such:

```html
<?php
  session_start();
include "dbconn.php";


  $query = "SELECT carid, brand FROM cars";
  $result = $dbcnx->query($query);

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $subcats[] = array("id" => $row['carid'], "val" => $row['brand']);
  }


  $jsonSubCats = json_encode($subcats);


?>

<!docytpe html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      <?php

        echo "var subcats = $jsonSubCats; \n";
      ?>
      function loadCategories(){
        var select = document.getElementById("categoriesSelect");
        select.onchange = updateSubCats;
      }
      function updateSubCats(){
        var catSelect = this;
        var catid = this.value;
        var subcatSelect = document.getElementById("subcatsSelect");
        subcatSelect.options.length = 0; //delete all options if any present
        for(var i = 0; i < subcats[catid].length; i++){
          subcatSelect.options[i] = new Option(subcats[catid][i].val,subcats[catid][i].id);
        }
      }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body onload='loadCategories()'>
            Car Category:<br />
        <select size="1" name="categoriesSelect" id="categoriesSelect">
           <option> Select Car Category  </option>
           <option value="sedan"> Sedan  </option>
           <option value="mpv"> MPV  </option>
           <option value="hatch"> Hatchback </option>
        </select><br /><br />

      Car Brand:<br />
    <select id='subcatsSelect'>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

I may have identified the error to the php statement:

```
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$subcats[] = array("id" => $row['carid'], "val" => $row['brand']);
```

As I can only see the first select box query correctly consisting of the 3 car category of MPV, Sedan and Hatchback.

Currently the all the Car Brand name appears however the results do not correspond with the car category as shown in the database.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both arrays in PHP follow the same pattern when created the json data will be similar also thus the method to traverse the data should follow that in `loadCategories` function - so perhaps this:

```
  function updateSubCats(){
    var oSelect = document.getElementById("subcatsSelect");
    oSelect.options.length = 0;

    for( var i in subcats ){
        oSelect.options[ i ]=new Option( subcats[ i ].val, subcats[ i ].id );
    }
  }
```

---

Without using Ajax or over complicating things with complex json iteration you could try along these lines. It should be noted that embedding the $_GET variable directly in the sql is not the best option - prepared statements would be better but should give the idea.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "dbconn.php";
?>

<!docytpe html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chained select</title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        function bindEvents(){
            document.getElementById('categories').addEventListener( 'change', getSubcategories, false );
        }

        function getSubcategories(e){
            var el=e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;
            var value=el.options[ el.options.selectedIndex ].value;
            location.search='?category='+value;
        }

        document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents, false );
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
        <select id='categories'>
        <?php

            $query = "SELECT carcat FROM cars";
            $result = $dbcnx->query($query);

            while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
                echo "<option value='{$cat['carcat']}'>{$cat['carcat']}";
            }

        ?>
        </select>
        <select id='subcategories'>
            <?php

                if( !empty( $_GET['category'] ) ){

                    $sql = "SELECT carid, brand FROM cars where carcat='{$_GET['category']}';";
                    $result = $dbcnx->query( $sql );

                    if( $result ){
                        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
                            echo "<option value='{$row['carid']}'>{$row['brand']}";
                        }
                    }
                }

            ?>
        </select>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just update my codes such that the Car Category select box would only consist of 3 static values. The code you provided still does not dynamically change the car brand select box. Thank You.

Comment: Yes I have just added the id but the problem still persists. Right now the "Brand" Select box is able to function however all the brand name would appear. The brand name should appear with the car category correspondingly as shown in the database. I have no idea where the problem is concentrated now. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ram Thanks for creating the codes. However it seems that the echo values for the options are faulty. As you have mentioned above that the GET_ values would create problems it seems that it does not display the results correctly. But I do get your idea of directly inserting the values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it won't, you're accessing your arrays wrong:

```
subcatSelect.options[i] = new Option(subcats[catid][i].val,subcats[catid][i].id);
                                     ^^^^^                         ^^^^^
```

Your subcats array is only 2-dimensional, yet you're accessing it as a 3-dimentional array here.

Comment: Sorry I don't get quite what you mean. Could you kindly show me the correct array? Perhaps I would understand upon looking at it. Thanks.

Comment: your subcats array is basically `$foo = array(array('id' => 42))`. one array inside another. But your js is treating it as if it was `array(array(array(id=>42))` there is no `catid` dimension on that array.

Comment: Sorry I just updated the codes to allow the first select box to only have static values. I know that it would change the query for the second car brand alot. I seek your patience as I am very new with jason values. Thank You.

Comment: nothing to do with "json values". but you can't just build a data structure one way, then use it in a completely different way elsewhere.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation to populate the second select box without any jquery or ajax methods? Thanks.